# ingress-nginx wasn't installed properly?

Tags: kubernetes, ingress-nginx

Now I'm using WSL 2 and Docker Desktop on Windows 10.

I created an YAML script to create an ingress for my microservices like below.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
```

And I installed ingress-nginx by following this [installation guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

I ran this command in the guide.

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

But when I ran `kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx`, `ingress-nginx-controller` shows `ImageInspectError`
[image: ImageInspectError]

And when I ran the command `kubectl apply -f ingress-srv.yaml`, it showed an error message.
[image: Ingress error message]

Can anyone please let me know what the issue is?

I removed the namespace `ingress-nginx` using this command `kubectl delete all  --all -n ingress-nginx` and ran the deploy script again.

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

But the issue still happened.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue deploying ingress-nginx controller. You need to first fix issues there before deploying the ingress. Because, only the nginx controller knows how to handle the ingress resources.

Since there is no much info about the controller deployment failure, you better add more details about the error. You can describe the controller pod and share its event and status to look into this further.

Comment: Yes, there was an issue when I installed ingress-nginx controller. So I removed all corrupted docker images and reinstalled. After that all work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It was because of the corrupted filesystem.

When I ran the ingress-nginx deployment command, there was a docker-desktop crash because of the lack of drive storage size.

So I removed all corrupted, unused or dangling docker images.

`docker system prune`

Also I deleted ingress-nginx and reinstalled.

`kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

After that, it worked well.

`kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx`

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-tgkfx        0/1     Completed   0          74m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-28l7q         0/1     Completed   3          74m
ingress-nginx-controller-7844b9db77-4dfvb   1/1     Running     0          74m
```